# Bubble sort programming via C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I wrote a program for bubble sort which is showing a run time error saying "NULL Pointer Assignment". The code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[6], j = 0, count = 0, i, temp;

  printf("Enter the number");

  for(i = 0; i< 4; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  while(count < 4)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      if(a[i] < a[++j])
      {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }

    count++;
  }

  printf("The sorted array is");

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("\n%d\n", a[i]);
  }

  getchar();
}
```

But When I tried the below code then it runs successfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[6], count=0, i, temp;

  printf("Enter the number");

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  while(count<4)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      if(a[i] < a[i + 1])
      {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
      }
    }

    count++;
  }

  printf("The sort array is");

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("\n%d\n", a[i]);
  }

  getchar();
}
```

So I need the reason that why my code is showing error, and why the 2nd code is working. I am a new learner in C so please explain to me the reason briefly and simply.

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, a very important tool for programmers. If you run your program in a debugger, it will catch things like crashes, and stop at the location of the crash. From there you can walk up the function call stack to your code (if the crash isn't there already) and examine the values of variables. Even if you can't solve the problem yourself, then at least please edit your question to show us *where* the crash happens in your code.

Comment: Using proper indentation will increase your code's readability tremendously.

Comment: By the way, in the first program, your inner loop when sorting, the variable `j` will go *way* out of bounds of the array `a`, leading to *undefined behavior*. And in your second program you will include the *fifth* element in the array when sorting, which you haven initialized so its value is *indeterminate*, once again leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You know can scanf more than a variable at a time doing something like this `scanf("%d %d %d %d", &var1, &var2, &var3, &var4)`?

Comment: What @JoachimPileborg says.  No aparrent attempt at debugging always gets a downvote from me, no matter how trivial or obvious the bug might appear from looking at the source.

Comment: please give me the name and link of the good debugger..and if u can then please give me the instruction "how to use it" coz I am new in programming..

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a `NULL pointer exception` is in the first program, by the completion of the first iteration of the while loop the value of `j` has become `4`. In the second iteration of the while loop the `j` value is not reset and continues from `4`. Trying to access `a[j]` when `j` is equal to `6` will result in a the said error.

```
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
          if(a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
              // swap
          }
      }
  }
```

Something like this will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you don't reset the variable ´j´ at the beginning of the outer while loop and `j` is increased in the inner for loop. So you are increasing `j` in each of the 4 outer while loop transitions for 4 times in the inner for loop. So `j` has already reached the value 4 after the first while loop round. In the second while loop round it will be incremented to 5, 6, 7, 8 etc. So just reset the variable `j` to `0` at the beginning of the while loop:

```
while(count<4)
{
    j = 0;
    for(...
```

By the way it's still not a good implementation because you are comparing the last value with an undefined value: `if(a[3] < a[4])`.
Whereas `a[3]` contains the last entered value the variable `a[4]` contains an undefined value. Therefore you should change the for loop to `for(i=0;i<3;i++)`.